# error in python extension with sfml in C++

Tags: python, c++, sfml

I have no knowledge in C++

And tried to do an extension in python to check if using SFML in
C++ code and use in python would work

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='init',
      version='1.0',
      ext_modules=[Extension('testemeu',['main.cpp'],include_dirs=[r"C:\Users\v\Documents\code\C\sml\SFML-2.4.2\include"],library_dirs = [r"C:\Users\v\Documents\code\C\sml\SFML-2.4.2\lib"])])
```

But this error appears:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'testemeu' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Users\v\Documents\code\C\sml\SFML-2.4.2
\include -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include -c main.cpp -o build\temp.w
in32-3.4\Release\main.o
writing build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\testemeu.def
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o build\temp.w
in32-3.4\Release\testemeu.def -LC:\Users\v\Documents\code\C\sml\SFML-2.4.2\lib -
LC:\Python34\libs -LC:\Python34\PCbuild -lpython34 -lmsvcr100 -o build\lib.win32
-3.4\testemeu.pyd
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference t
o `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x98): undefined reference t
o `_imp___ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference t
o `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettin
gsE'
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference t
o `_imp___ZNK2sf6Window6isOpenEv'
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x119): undefined reference
to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window9pollEventERNS_5EventE'
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x135): undefined reference
to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window5closeEv'
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x13c): undefined reference
to `_imp___ZN2sf5Color5BlackE'
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x14b): undefined reference
to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget5clearERKNS_5ColorE'
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference
to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window7displayEv'
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x192): undefined reference
to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1af): undefined reference
to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

How to fix this?

Comment: These are linker errors, it means that declarations were found during compilation but when it got to linking it couldn't find the definitions of those functions. Perhaps you forgot to link against some library?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to link to some libraries in your command.
I found out a few libraries you could link to. Add this to your compiler command and swap `<sfml-install-path>` with your own install path

```
-L<sfml-install-path>/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh they didn't link to any static libraries in the compile command though (you can see it in his question) I looked at the SFML starting guide and you need to link to those libraries (my answer is from their starting guide)

Comment: How to do this with distutils?

Comment: I read the documentation and found out where to put these libraries in distutils

Comment: @walle So do you still need help or are you fine now?